# Flutter: Need to trigger / re-run the StreamProvider QuerySnapshot stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

Using Flutter / Dart, Provider: ^4.1.2 / cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6.

Provider setup in main.dart:

```
//companyId will be saved in this changeNotifier class with a `notifyListeners();`
ChangeNotifierProvider<SharedPreferencesData>(
      create: (context) => SharedPreferencesData(), 
    ),

//when companyId is saved above, it'll trigger the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<SharedPreferencesData, DatabaseService>(
  create: (_) => DatabaseService(),
  update: (_, sharedPreferencesData, databaseService) {
    databaseService.sPData = sharedPreferencesData;
    return databaseService;
  },
    ),
  ],
  child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext bCtx) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [

//This StreamProvier should update when DatabaseService ChangeNotifierProxyProvider is triggered:
    StreamProvider<List<Location>>.value(
      value: Provider.of<DatabaseService>(bCtx).getLocations,
      initialData: List(),
    ),
```

sharedPreferences file:

```
class SharedPreferencesData with ChangeNotifier {
  var _sharedPreferencesData = SharedPreferences(
    companyId: '',
  );
  void setSharedPrefDataCompanyId(String companyId) {
    final newSharedPreferences = SharedPreferences(
      companyId: companyId,
    );
    _sharedPreferencesData = newSharedPreferences;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

database file to configure the stream:

```
  Stream<List<Location>> get getLocations {
//companyId won't be ready when the app runs at first
    var companyId = sPData.getSharedPreferencesData().companyId;
    return locationsCollection
        .where('companyId', isEqualTo: companyId)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_locationsListFromSnapshot); ===> this method to convert the QuerySnapshot to List<Location>
  }
```

Listening to the StreamProvider in a new screen/file:

```
final locations = Provider.of<List<Location>>(context);
```

When the app runs, the companyId will be empty, and therefore the Locations stream gets updated but returning empty List. Then the String companyId will be assigned, `Stream<List<Location>>` does not run again when `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<SharedPreferencesData, DatabaseService>` runs. and therefore get correct Locations using updated companyId.

Note: I've noticed that the above behavior occur only when I fully STOP main.dart and then Run main.dart BUT if the app is already running, and I press Run main.dart (not Flutter Hot reload), the Stream<List> runs at first with an empty list, BUT then is triggered somehow and get correct Locations with correct companyId.

- How can I trigger Stream<List> (after companyId is added)?
- Why when STOP/RUN `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<SharedPreferencesData, DatabaseService>` is NOT triggering Locations stream, but if only hitting RUN, Locations Stream is being triggerd and app works correctly.
- What is the difference between STOP / RUN ... and (app is already running) => RUN (not hot reload)? in a way that is affecting the logic behavior of the app.

Comment: Why do you need a StreamProvider here? Can't you listen to the equivalent of "getLocations" directly from DatabaseService?

Comment: Whenever I need to use Locations, I start with `final locations = Provider.of<List<Location>>(context);` and then I have access to that stream converted to a List. What do you mean by listening directly from DatabaseService? And, would that fix the problem i have?

Comment: In case accessing the stream directly from DatabaseService solved my problem, and updated the stream with companyId. What would be the problem then with my current logic? Why would `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` not handle this correctly? What am I missing...

Comment: The problem is, what you tried to do is not _update_ the previous stream but instead _create_ a new stream. But StreamProvider is listening to the previous stream not the new one.

Comment: @RémiRousselet even with `value: Provider.of<DatabaseService>(bCtx).getLocations` I am not listening to the most _updated_ version of the _stream_?
This is being really confusing! at least for me, 
With my setup, how can I make sure I am always listening to the most updated version of Streams in DatabaseServices.

Comment: You're probably missing a notifyListeners inside DatabaseService when companyId changes

Comment: Are you having a specific issue with Cloud Firestore?

Comment: @RémiRousselet app is working ok now. yet I'm still having some unnecessary loops I can avoid on launch. Thank you Remi!

Comment: @MrTech no not related to Firestore, why?